# How to set TActionClientItem.CommandProperties at runtime?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I using delphi XE2. I am dynamically creating a Ribbon, have created the ribbontabs and ribbon groups and have actions in the groups. I can set the CommandStyle but cannot see how to set the CommandProperties for the action. ie for a CommandStyle item of csButton how do i set the Commandproperties buttonsize to bsSmall?

Please help!!
Regards

Comment: I'm going to go with testing `if CommandProperties is TButtonProperties then (CommandProperties as TButtonProperties).ButtonSize := bsSmall`; but I don't have delphi to hand to check

Comment: Hello Petesh, doing well is just what I needed thank you very much. 
Best regards.